# proof involving special set

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs

> For this question, $\left({n\choose k}\right)$ denotes the number of multisets of size $k$ with elements from $[1,\cdots, n].$ For instance, there are $3$ multisets of size $2$ from the set $[1,2],$ namely $[1,2],[1,1],$ and $[2,2].$ Here, the notation $[\cdot]$ and $\{\cdot\}$ is just used to distinguish multisets from regular sets. $[1,2] = \{1,2\}$ but $[1,1] \neq \{1,1\} = \{1\}.$ Prove that $\left({n\choose k}\right) = \sum_{j=0}^k \left({n-1\choose j}\right)$.

Let $S$ represent the set of multisets of size $k$ from $[1,\cdots, n], S_j$ represent the set of subsets of size $j$ from $\{1,\cdots, n\}, T_{k-j}$ represent the set of multisets of size $k-j$ from $S_j$, and $U_j$ represent the set of multisets of size $k$ with $j$ distinct elements from $[1,\cdots, n]$. We have that $|S| = \left({n\choose k}\right)$. Observe that $|S_j| = {n\choose j}$ and $|T_{k-j}| = \left({j\choose k-j}\right)$. Observe that each $k$-multiset of $[1,\cdots, n]$ has between $1$ and $k$ distinct elements. We have that $U_0 = \emptyset$, so $S = \cup_{j=0}^k U_j$. I know how to find a bijection $f \colon U_j \to S_j\times T_{k-j}$ to show that the sets have the same cardinality. This, coupled with the fact that the $U_j$s are disjoint, shows that $|S| = \sum_{j=0}^k |U_j| = \sum_{j=0}^k {n\choose j}\left({j\choose k-j}\right)$.

> Is this correct?

Comment: Note that $\left({n\choose k}\right) = \sum_{j=0}^k \left({n-1\choose j}\right)$ can be thought of as the multiset version of $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ with essentially the same combinatorial proof.  Instead of conditioning on whether $n$ is in the set or not, just condition on how many occurrences of $n$ is in the multiset.

Comment: What exactly is the bijection? And how do you get from the last step in your proof to the final result?

Comment: @inavda I omitted those details because I already know them. Try to come up with the bijection by yourself. If you cannot, then I suppose I can add it.

Comment: I'll take your word for it for now :) but everything else in the proof looks solid.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Hi, just for curiosity...I never have seen the $\left({n\choose k}\right)$ double symbols of rounded brackets. Where can I see a book with this notation and numerical examplese? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Since it reduces directly to binomial coefficients by stars-and-bars, it doesn't get a lot of individualized attention.  I would guess any enumerative combinatorics book would have at least a section on it (perhaps with a different notation). See also [the multiset article in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have ask recently a question with your same link :-)...thank you very much.

Comment: No!  It's not correct because it was tagged  elementary set theory which it is not.

Comment: @WilliamElliot so is it correct now?